# Changing water-purification to water-treatment

Tags: discussion, tags

The term "purification" has specific connotations which implies that there will be no remaining contamination. In the great outdoors as well domestically, we never really purify water, we treat it in order to reduce levels of contamination down to a level where our bodies can cope. It is certainly misleading to suggest that we are making water pure by adding chemicals such as chlorine and iodine.

UPDATE

This Google Trends analysis shows that Water Treatment is a significantly more searched for term.

http://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore#q=water%20treatment%2C%20%20water%20purification&cmpt=q

Comment: Someone with rep or moderator privileges could create a tag synonym for now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, change the tag to [water-treatment](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-treatment).

**Note**: REI also use the term [water treatment](http://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/water-treatment-backcountry.html).

Comment: Is there specific protocol for this type of thing? Up vote the one you want, down vote the one you don't?

Comment: @stevemarvell Yes, upvote the one you want and/or downvote the other, depending on how strongly you feel about them. It's not always done as explicitly as this, but it's convenient.

Comment: It's silly that you can't upvote your own answers in meta.

Comment: Might be the only time you can say "+1" and get away with it.

Answer (score 2):

No, keep the tag as [water-purification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-purification).